# How to output failed test's strack traces to the console

Tags: java, maven-2, junit, surefire

I'm running a single test from Maven:

`mvn test -Dtest=TestCircle`

If the test fails, Maven outputs the exceptions in `/target/...` folder.

Is there a way to tell Maven that this exception should be printed directly on the console, so I don't have to look in `/target/surefire-reports/...`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can configure the surefire plugin to *generate a file test report or just output the test report to the console* using the [`useFile`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#useFile) optional parameter:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
      <useFile>false</useFile>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Or, from the command line with the corresponding expression:

```
$ mvn test -Dsurefire.useFile=false
```